Principle in between BPI and AC
I have searched extensively in the literature, but all references I have consulted always place BPI (the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem) as a sort of "cover" of the Axiom of Choice as far as consistency strength goes. Are there natural principles which are consequences of choice, and which imply BPI, which are known to be weaker than choice? Or at least, are there any plausible candidates which people have considered?

Here would be a good place to start looking.

BPI, not BIP...

This might also be a good place to look for it: https://github.com/ioannad/jeffrey
